# Updating CoreData Entity or saving a new one

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm fairly new to CoreData, and I'm trying to make a game. I have a couple of questions I was hoping you guys could help me out with some guidance:
- does GameKit already have some sort of CoreData integrated in it? I am not sure if I am overthinking this CoreData stuff if there's already something that replaces it in GameKit.
. . .
Anyways, assuming the answer to the above question is "no. GameKit has nothing to save your game". I will proceed with my current "Save game" code which is the following:

```
func saveCurrentMatch()
    {
        /* CORE DATA STUFF:
         FIRST NEED TO VERIFY IF THIS GAME HAS BEEN PREVIOUSLY SAVED, IF SO THEN UPDATE, ELSE JUST SAVE
         Entity: MatchData
         Attributes: scoreArray (String), playerArray (String), myScore (Int), matchID (Int), isWaiting (Bool), isRealTime (Bool), gameLog (String)
         */

        let context = myAppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "MatchData")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do
        {
            let gamesInProgress = try context.fetch(request)
            print (gamesInProgress.count)

            if gamesInProgress.count > 0 //HERE CHANGE THIS TO LOOK FOR THE MATCH ID OF THIS GAME!!
            {
                gameExistsinCD = true
            }
            else
            {
                gameExistsinCD = false
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print ("Error Reading Data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if gameExistsinCD
        {
            //CODE TO UPDATE MATCH INSTEAD OF SAVING NEW ONE
        }
        else
        {
            // CODE TO SAVE A NEW MATCH FOR THE FIRST TIME
            let matchData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "MatchData", into: context)

            matchData.setValue(isRealTime, forKey: "isRealTime")
            matchData.setValue(currentScore?[0], forKey: "myScore")
            matchData.setValue(currentScore?.map{String($0)}.joined(separator: "\t"), forKey: "scoreArray") // IS THIS CODE CORRECT? I'M TRYING TO SAVE AN ARRAY OF INTS INTO A SINGLE STRING
            matchData.setValue(currentPlayers?.joined(separator: "\t"), forKey: "playerArray")
            matchData.setValue(true, forKey: "isWaiting") //will change later to update accordingly.
            matchData.setValue(matchID, forKey: "matchID")
            matchData.setValue(gameLog, forKey: "gameLog")

            do
            {
                try context.save()
                print ("CoreData: Game Saved!")
            }
            catch
            {
                print ("Error Saving Data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

My main concern is on the fetch request, how do I check all the core-data if this match has already been saved? and if so, whats the code for updating an Entity instead of inserting a new one?
Any guidance is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: (This is not an answer but just a note) In your case I believe using core data would be completely inappropriate. It is slow, wasteful, hard to maintain while you have no bonus at all. I would in your case either use `JSONSerialization` to convert data from-to JSON and save it to file. Or maybe even better in your case is `Codable`.

Comment: I am using Codable and JSON files to load some of the game assets, however to store a game itself (from what I've read online here and in Reddit) I was pointed in the CoreData direction. Note there are multiple matches going on at the same time so some will get updated and deleted as they end. its not a one-match game.

Comment: I would need more detail on that but the result is most likely still NO. Use core data where you have references or connections between some objects, where you need some queries done to fetch specific data. In your case I would say each mach is presented by a single JSON or Codable file. To update it open it, modify it and save it back; or even keep it in memory and just synchronize it on change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't let Core Data scare you. It can be a fine way to save local data and despite some comments, it is not slow when done right. In fact, Core Data can be quite fast.

You can simplify your code a lot by using your Object class in a more normal fashion instead of using setValue calls. Your create code can be changed to this:

```
// CODE TO SAVE A NEW MATCH FOR THE FIRST TIME
if let matchData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "MatchData", into: context) as? MatchData {

    matchData.isRealTime = isRealTime
    matchData.myScore = currentScore?[0]
    matchData.scoreArray = currentScore?.map{String($0)}.joined(separator: "\t") // IS THIS CODE CORRECT? I'M TRYING TO SAVE AN ARRAY OF INTS INTO A SINGLE STRING
    // You can certainly save it this way and code it in and out. A better alternative is to have a child relationship to another managed object class that has the scores.
    matchData.playerArray = currentPlayers?.joined(separator: "\t")
    matchData.isWaiting = true
    matchData.matchID = matchID
    matchData.gameLog = gameLog
}
```

This is a much more readable and normal way to set your object properties. Any time you change a property on a core data managed object then it will get saved the next time you save the context.

As far as finding a current record that matches the ID, I like to add classes like that to my Managed Object class itself:

```
class func findByID(_ matchID: String) -> MatchData? {
    let myAppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = myAppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "MatchData")
    let idPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "matchID = \(matchID)", argumentArray: nil)
    request.predicate = idPredicate
    var result: [AnyObject]?
    var matchData: MatchData? = nil
    do {
        result = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        NSLog("Error getting match: \(error)")
        result = nil
    }
    if result != nil {
        for resultItem : AnyObject in result! {
            matchData = resultItem as? MatchData
        }
    }
    return matchData
}
```

Then any place you need the match data by ID you can call the class function:

```
if let matchData = MatchData.findByID("SomeMatchID") {
    // Match exists
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that was really helpful. I'll try to implement it this way. I was wondering on your take on Matic  Oblaks comment about using JSONs instead. The game itself consists of simple matches (as you can see they only have that set of data) and a user can have multiple matches going on at the same type (while waiting on his turn in other matches). I am not sure if CoreData is the most appropriate way but I've been pointed in so many directions It's hard to say which is the best.

Comment: I'm a fan of Core Data (and other frameworks on top of it like Realm) for even simple data storage. It makes querying data so much easier instead of looping arrays. JSON storage is simple, but not robust. If your app will have any kind of querying of the different matches, even simple querying, I think you'll find Core Data helpful. If you're worried about the complexity of contexts just keep all of it in a single context or else use something like Realm which manages it all for you.

Comment: One final thing, where do I declare a class function? I mean the Entity was declared in the xdatamodel file in xCode, so do I also have to make a MatchData class additional to the MatchData entity? if so how does swift know when I'm referring to the class or to the entity? or are these interchangeable?

Comment: Sorry, another question. Assuming I reuse the line "let myAppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate" in another swift file, will it create another instance or will it be the same? like can I save into ViewController1.myAppDelegate.context and load that same file from ViewController2.myAppDelegate.context ??

Comment: yes, you create a MatchData class. While you have the data model open you can select the entity on the left and from the Editor menu choose Create NSManageObject subclass and it will walk you through creating the Swift class for your entity.

Comment: Each reference to the app delegate points to the same instance. It is a singleton.

Comment: I am sorry for my ignorance, but when I did that (Editor > Create NSMAnagedObject subclass) 2 new files came up (one properties and one class). I declared the class func in the class file and xCode says "MatchData has no member findByID". I tried moving the func declaration to the other file (the properties file) and I got the same error. Am I doing something wrong? Also, these 2 files are outside (at the top) of the file tree, is this normal? shouldn't they fall "under" the project folder?

Comment: Put the class function in the class file, not in the properties extension file. Be sure your two new have the Target Membership correctly checked for your target so the compiler sees them. You can drag the files inside a group folder. I usually put all my managed objects classes in a Model group. But that won't affect whether your code can see it.

Comment: I finally fixed everything. Just an FYI that that code (the "fetchbyID" function) crashes the app. I am not sure exactly where but I've tried multiple things to lock-down where the error was and its somewhere in that code (018-01-15 22:24:57.487422+0800 CoreData+Collections[2868:125798] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException')

Answer (score 1):

Core data is basically wrapper around SQL database. It is very efficient when you are working with high volume of data that need to be stored. So please consider either you had such requirements, otherwise perhaps it can be wise to store data in user defaults, or settings.

If it is, there is few things you need to know.

1. It is very useful to create you own model classes. Open core data model file, open "Editor/Create NSManagedObject subclass". It will allow you to refer direct properties, instead of KVC(setValue:forKey:).
2. Alway mind what thread you are working in. It is unsafe to work with objects, created in other threads.
3. Your **gamesInProgress** contains array of objects you fetched from your database.

So basically instead of

```
  if gameExistsinCD
        {
            //CODE TO UPDATE MATCH INSTEAD OF SAVING NEW ONE
        }
        else
        {
            // CODE TO SAVE A NEW MATCH FOR THE FIRST TIME
            let matchData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "MatchData", into: context)
            matchData.setValue(isRealTime, forKey: "isRealTime")
            <...>
```

you can do

```
let matchData =  (gamesInProgress.first ??      
NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "MatchData", into: context)) as! <YouEntityClass>  
matchData.isRealTime = isRealTime
<...>
```

PS: https://www.raywenderlich.com/173972/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial-2